# Client UI for DBreeze

Tags: gratis, linux, .net, database-browser, nosql

[DBreeze](http://dbreeze.codeplex.com/) is a C# NoSQL embedded database.

Is there any easy tool to browse data contained in a DBreeze file?
Like SQLiteBrowser for SQLite.

Requirement:

- Runs on Linux
- Free, ideally open source
- CLI is OK but GUI is better

Comment: Author says: > Nope, data is heterogeneous and schemaless, may be [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) can be handy as a 3rd party tool https://github.com/hhblaze/DBreeze/issues/47 So no, not really.